# Join in Cognos Data Module returns error message

Tags: sql, database, cognos

I want to perform a simple join of two tables. Each Table has only one row.
The join column should be "DP". The Value for DP is "India" in both Tables. The Value comes from a calucation (see screenshot). When I perform the join (full outer join, 1 to 1, no filtering) I receive this error message:

> XQE-DAT-0001 Data source adapter error message:Detected implicit
> cartesian product for FULL OUTER join between logical plans Project
> [India AS DP#384910, Year_#369960, Net_Sales#369961]
> +- Relation[Year_#369960,Net_Sales#369961] parquet and Relation[Industry#369945,Value_#369946] parquet Join condition is
> missing or trivial.

[image: Calculation]

[image: Column to join]

[image: Join Statement]

Comment: Did you press the match selected columns button?  Your screen capture of the relationship editor shows that no columns were matched.

Where did you get the data?  Do you consider it possible that the year and industry values exist together in the source, if not in the same table already then in the same data base in related tables.

Comment: Yes, I pressed the button. The data is not available in the same table.

Comment: Where did you get the data? Do you consider it possible that the year and industry values exist together in the source, if not in the same table already then in the same data base in related tables.

Comment: You have tables, one with one column and the other with two columns, created by uploading files.  You are trying to join them by creating an expression to create a column to be used as the key.  The query engine is complaining, possibly because the key column does not exist in the parquet db created from the uploaded files.  Did you try an option other than full outer join?  Do you understand that whatever data you get out of this exercise is possibly going to be suspect?

Comment: @C'estMoi The data is coming from relational data models stored in our data warehouse. I created datasets based on the relational data models and loaded these datasets into the data module.  Each Table has three columns, but I want to join only on one column (DP). I tried every possible combination of cardinality and join-type and it is not working.

Comment: If the dimensions and facts which you are trying to use exist in a data base then, if the dimensions are conformed to the facts you want to use, it should be a doddle to get the information you want from a report, without needing to muck about with data sets, without more detail about why you believe you need to create them.   It is possible that you do need data sets, for example because you want to preaggregate things.  Even if so, you would need to have more metadata in the data sets to properly design a model so that the query engine can execute queries which will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you received indicates that there is an issue with the join condition in your query. You're doing a FULL OUTER JOIN without specificy the column on which to join, which is similar to a full cartesian join (called "CROSS" join).

To fix this issue, you need to specify a valid join condition that relates the tables based on the "DP" column.

Comment: But what would be the correct join condition? Full outer Join should be correct in my opinion. And DP only has the value "India" in both tables. Therefore I do not understand how to fix the problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my Join Statement to the post.

Comment: Please read Jerome's answer.

Comment: @dougp  I tried every possible combination of cardinality and join-type and it is not working. Also, I specified the columns to join in both tables.

Comment: @Jérôme Radix I tried every possible combination of cardinality and join-type and it is not working. Also, I specified the columns to join in both tables.

Comment: cardinality and join-type don't matter if you have not defined any joins.  You need to select the column from each table, then click the "Match Selected Columns" button.  Your screen capture indicates you have not yet clicked the button.